# How to align the bottom of a View with the Software Keyboard?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to make a `LinearLayout` align with the Software Keyboard when it is showing.

My `LinearLayout` contains an `EditText` to which the Software Keyboard is always being aligned.

The whole `View` (`LinearLayout`) looks like this:

[image]

When gaining focus to edit the `EditText` keyboard aligns itself to the `EditText` instead of the whole `View`:

[image]

I know that in the *Material Design Library* there is a `TextInputLayout` which also is a `LinearLayout` containing an `EditText`. When focusing on the `EditText` wrapped in the `TextInputLayout` the whole `LinearLayout` is aligned with the keyboard:

[image]

Now, I've seen people tell that I should add a `windowSoftInputMode` parameter in the `<activity>`:

```xml
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

which does not work. Also I've seen many other answers on that issue but all of them referred to setting flags and parameters outside of the `View` itself but within the `Activity`'s `Window` which is not what I want.

Here is the code that approximates mine - it has the dependencies that the `CustomEditText` has:

```java
public class TestEditText extends LinearLayoutCompat {
 
    public TestEditText(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        initTestEditText();
    }
 
    public TestEditText(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initTestEditText();
    }
 
    public TestEditText(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initTestEditText();
    }
 
    // Layout in which there is an EditText - additional views, like buttons can be here
    private LinearLayoutCompat textInputLayout;
 
    private AppCompatEditText editText;
 
    private void initTestEditText() {
        setOrientation(VERTICAL);
        setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
 
        // Getting states from children - in this case from another LinearLayout
        setAddStatesFromChildren(true);
 
        prepareTextInputLayout();
        prepareEditText();
    }
 
    private void prepareTextInputLayout() {
        textInputLayout = new LinearLayoutCompat(getContext());
 
 
        textInputLayout.setLayoutParams(
                new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, dpToPx(128))
        );
        textInputLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
 
        // Getting the states from children - in this case from an editText
        textInputLayout.setAddStatesFromChildren(true);
 
        addView(textInputLayout);
    }
 
    private void prepareEditText() {
        editText = new AppCompatEditText(getContext());
 
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                1
        );
        editText.setLayoutParams(params);
        editText.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
 
        editText.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
 
        editText.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
        editText.setTextSize(14);
 
        textInputLayout.addView(editText);
    }
 
    private int dpToPx(int dp) {
        return (int) (dp * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }
}
```

There has to be some way to make the bottom of a `View` align with the Software Keyboard, because `TextInputLayout` does **exactly that** without setting any flags in the `<activity>`...

If You have any other idea, please help.